# What is the best way to fake a SQL array or list?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, list

I'm building a chatroom application, and I want to keep track of which users are currently in the chatroom. However, I can't just store this array of users (or maybe a list would be better) in a field in one of my records in the Chatroom table.

> Obviously one of the SQL data types is not an array, which leads me to this issue: what is the best way to fake/mock array functionality in a SQL database?

It seems there are 3 options:

**1:** Store the list/array of users as a string separated by commas, and just do some parsing when I want to get it back to an array

**2:** Since the max amount of users is allowed to be 10, just have 10 extra fields on each Chatroom record representing the users who are currently there

**3:** Have a new table Userchats, which has two fields, a reference to the chatroom, and a user name

I dunno, which is the best? I'm also open to other options. I'm also using Rails, which seems irrelevant here, but may be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 3 is the best. This is how you do it, in a relational schema. It is also the most flexible and future-proof option.

It can grow easier in width (extra columns say, a date joined, a channel status, a timestamp last talked) and length (extra rows when you decide there now can be 15 users in a room instead of 10).

Comment: And storing data in a delimited list usually turns into a nightmare the minute you want to query on any individual item in the list such as a query to see what chatrooms a particular user is in right now.

Comment: @Konerak Thanks. My only concern with this method is when I have to fetch these records... Considering that there will be a lot of Chatrooms, there are going to be about 10 times as many Userchats, indicating an expensive find

Comment: @varatis, this is valid concern but if your table is indexed properly, option 3 will still net the best solution (performance as well as flexibility).  be sure to have a good purge/archive process if you fear it'll grow fast.

Comment: @varatis: fetching still will be faster like this. Imagine when you are using comma separated values, and a user disconnects. You'd have to check each individual chatroom for the user...

Comment: I upvoted this answer.  And I'm going to add that this really ought to be in a FAQ.  The question about creating a CSV list in a column versus creating a related child table has been asked dozens of times.  By now, we should be able to point askers to convincing proof that the performance gains of parsing columns are an llusion, while the programming nightmares are real.

Answer (score 0):

The *proper* way to do this is to add an extra table representing an instance of a user being in a chatroom. In most cases, this is probably what you will want to do, since it gives you more flexibility in the types of queries you can do (for instance: list all chatrooms a particular user is in, find the average number of people in each chatroom, etc.) You would just need to add a new table - something like `chat_room_users`, with a `chat_room_id`, and a `user_id`.

If you're deadset on not adding an extra table, then Rails (or more specifically ActiveRecord), does have some functionality to store data structures like arrays in a SQL column. Just set up your column as a `string` or `text` type in a Rails migration, and add:

```
serialize :users
```

You can then use this column as a normal Ruby array / object, and ActiveRecord will automatically serialize / deserialize this object as you work with it. Keep in mind that's there are a lot of tradeoffs with this approach - you will never be able to query what users are in a particular room using SQL and will instead need to pull all data down to Ruby before working with it.